# How to play video and audio at the same time

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I need to play a video (webm) and an audio (m4a) file at the same time on a browser that only accepts one media playing at a time (if I try to play them simultaneously on separate `<video>` and `<audio>` elements, the previous gets paused automatically).

Does anyone know what can I do?

Comment: You could try **Media Source Extensions**. Test with short clips (5 seconds) where you do what's needed to play a webM then also test playing an M4A. When you have code to play either media type anytime, then try append both buffers. Load the media file's bytes into Arrays and append those buffers (Arrays).

Comment: @VC.One Is it possible to stream both of them? Because I only could make it work by having them both totally downloaded before they start playing together.

Comment: Is this because of loading into Arrays? Meaning you have to wait for loading to complete before the array can be appended?

Comment: @VC.One I'm not sure. Here's my current code: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/italodeandra/144b7036318467a6c49591d7b4960abd/raw/9279e6f770dbf63f676784fe208e1ec3499f737f/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Control the play of two media using JavaScript.
Try this:

```js
function Players() {
    var audio_player = document.getElementById('audio');
    var video_player = document.getElementById('video');
    audio_player.play();
    video_player.play();
}
```

```html
<button onClick="Players()">PLAY</button>

<br>
<br>

<audio id="audio" controls="controls">     
  <source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<br>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Hi Maria, thanks for the answer but I specifically said that this solution doesn't work on browsers that only allows one media playing at a time.

Comment: @italodeandra I tested it on webkit browsers like Firefox and Chrome that works properly without problem. Please note that the correct audio and video address must be included in my code for it to work properly. If you still have this problem, tell me the browser that has this problem.

Comment: Two of those browsers are: WebOS on TVs and iOS Safari on iPhones (not inline).